# Is there a faster way to compare NSBitmapImageRep objects pixel by pixel?

Tags: objective-c, performance, core-graphics, getpixel, nsbitmapimagerep

I'm trying to speed up some code that i wrote a while back.

Using instruments in Xcode I've found that the major bottleneck is in this method, in particular the getPixel call.

```
- (BOOL)fasterCompareImage:(NSBitmapImageRep *)imageRepA IdenticalTo:(NSBitmapImageRep *)imageRepB {

    // look for obvious differences ie: width and height differences...
    NSSize imageASize = [imageRepA size];
    NSSize imageBSize = [imageRepB size];
    if( (imageASize.width != imageBSize.width) || (imageASize.height != imageBSize.height) ) {
        return NO;
    }

    // now start looking at each point
    NSUInteger pixelOfA[3];  
    NSUInteger pixelOfB[3];  

    for (int row = 0; row < (imageASize.height); row = row +1) { 
        for(int col = 0; col < (imageASize.width); col = col +1) { 
            [imageRepA getPixel:pixelOfA atX:row y:col];
            [imageRepB getPixel:pixelOfB atX:row y:col];

            if(pixelOfA[1] != pixelOfB[1]) {  
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Basically my method takes two NSBitmapImageRep objects and compares them pixel by pixel to look for differences.

Does anyone have any advice on the code or perhaps a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

Monty, when you use intensive loops like you did, you should not use lot of obj-c calls.

NSBitmapImageRep holds a CGImage reference. And you can use the CFEqual in order to compare 2 CFStruct, wich CGImage is. After that, you just need to cross yours fingers that the equality on CGImage is about pixel, chanel, bitmap info, and lot more... I don't know what is conceptually two same images identical. But you have lot of tools here in order to do what you want.

Sorry if that's not actually a response, but i give you big hints on the way you should accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks Mr Bonjour.  I'll explore some of your suggestions in the next few days and report back.  Appreciate the pointers :)

Comment: Hi Mr Bonjour,  I explored using CGImageRef as suggested and the speed has doubled :)   I couldn't get CFEqual working so instead have been comparing the bytes in each CGImageRef which is actually stored in a CFDataRef (inside CGImageRef).  Getting the CFDataRef to compare the bytes is a really expensive operation.  I'm using the function CGDataProviderCopyData(...) to do this.  Can you suggest another way or explain how i can use CFEqual to compare CGImages?

Comment: Ok i now realise why CFEqual didn't appear to be working.  It's because there are other attributes other than the pixel data stored in CGImageRef (such as bitsPerPixel) and CFEqual compares them all.   For anyone else looking for a really fast way to compare images use CFImageRef 'objects' rather than their NS... counterparts and call CFEqual to compare them.   Make sure you realise that CFEqual will compare all attributes not just the pixel data.  Thanks Mr Bonjour you set me off in the right direction :)